# What is the difference for margin?

Tags: css, margin

How to read this css parameter:

```
.gallery {
margin: 0 auto 18px;
}
```

What will get wrong if I remove the "18px"?

Comment: RTFM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin

Comment: -1 A useful tip is to do a google search first, before asking it here. For example, if you google search "css margin", the first result explains it very well.

Answer (score 4):

example

```
margin: 10px 20px 30px 40px;
```

the 10px is the top margin
the 20px is the right margin
the 30px is the bottom margin
the 40px is the left margin

example2

```
margin: 10px 20px;
```

the 10px is the top and bottom margin
the 20px is the left and right margin

example3

```
margin: 10px;
```

the 10px is the top, right, bottom, and left margin

example4

```
margin: 0 auto 18px;
```

the 0 is the top margin
the auto is the left and right margin
the 18px is the bottom margin

so by removing 18px , your bottom margin will turn to 0

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the 18px the bottom margin will be reset to 0.

Answer (score 0):

18px is the bottom margin. If you remove it, then top and bottom will have margin 0, while left and right will remain auto.

If there are 3 values set, then the first one is top, the second one is left and right, while the last one is bottom.

You can read more [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html).